# How can I protect my source code when running a Flask application with uWSGI?

Tags: python, flask, pyinstaller, uwsgi

I have a Flask application application that I run with uWSGI. My clients have access to the server where the app runs.

How can I protect or hide my source code?

Edit: I found that you can embed an app in uWSGI by [building it from source](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Embed.html), but that seems far fetched.

Comment: Why would you pack a flaskapp into a binary? The backend logic and jinja templating logic is invisible to the users of your website/serivce. I don't understand why you would want to convert it into a binary in the first place?

Comment: The users only see the HTML/CSS/JS because the browsers require that to render the content

Comment: @JackofSpades the api runs on on premise servers that are not ours. We don't want our clients to have access to our source code

Comment: Maybe I should rephrase the question: how can I protect/hide my source code when running a flask api with uWSGI?

Comment: Then I would strongly suggest you develop it in a different language, perhaps a language like go. If they have physical access to the server (or even remote access) your source code won't be secure, and there's tools out there to get the source code from python src converted to binary, such as this one which I found in less than a minute: https://github.com/countercept/python-exe-unpacker/blob/master/pyinstxtractor.py

Comment: Or, just run the service on your own servers. Which is the best option for the concerns you have

Comment: If you want to be sure that nobody can get your code, the bottom line, is don't hand over your code in any format. This includes access to the machines your code runs on.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your input! I'll leave the question open in case someone else comes up with a different solution

Comment: You might want to rephrase your question or ask a different question asking how you can run a webserver on a server provided by clients you don't TRUST with your backend/source code. The focus here should be security if you don't trust them for whatever reason (which it seems to be the case)

Also, consider if your database is being hosted on that server, if so, that's another problem.

Chances are, most legitimate server providers won't even look at your code/DB, but since your concerned, a post on one of stackoverflows sister sites probably isn't a bad idea.

Comment: Ok, thanks. The db is not a problem.

Comment: You might also be interested in this, saw this on reddit a few days ago or so
https://www.reddit.com/r/flask/comments/jg4dur/do_not_leak_your_secret_key_heres_how_an_attacker

Note: That file that contains his secret key was very likely explicity setup to return the source code at that endpoint, probably for pen-testing reasons? That is absolutely not the default behavior for flask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

True - if someone wants it badly enough, the only way to truly secure your algorithms is not to hand them out. But, reality is that code is hard to understand anyway. Often, just not documenting code is enough to discourage. There are some techniques, however, and your effort varies with how secure they are. Some approaches that come to mind are.

- Compile to bytecode: I've seen it done in the wild, there was company that made a Python email client for Linux / Outlook. I recall that it was obfuscated through a compiled distribution. You'd have to research the proper tool.
- Obfuscate at a per-script level: Check out the [pyminifier](https://liftoff.github.io/pyminifier/) tool. It can make your scripts pretty near impossible to read (but it can be reversed with reasonable effort)
- Use an advanced obfuscator: Look at [pyarmor](https://pypi.org/project/pyarmor/). It is a lot more complex and will be harder to implement -- but it looks like it would get the job done.
- Open source it. Seems counter intuitive -- but algorithms are rarely the most valuable aspect of code. Having the skill, time, resources to understand and maintain it is. It is very likely that it doesn't matter if anyone sees your code. If you are giving a good service to your customer, they generally have much better things to do than to take on your code base. There are plenty of enterprise companies making a living from open source software (eg. Startburst, 2nd Quadrant.)

(Example code obfuscated using pyminifier)

```
import argparse
ۻﲮᆖﻆ=range
ۻﲮᆖﻆ枇=int
ۻﲮᆖﻆ=print
ۻﲮᆖﻆﶾ=argparse.ArgumentParser
import sys
ۻﲮᆖﻆ=sys.argv
ۻﲮᆖﻆ=sys.stdout
import logging
ۻﲮᆖﻆ닸=logging.basicConfig
ۻﲮᆖﻆ=logging.DEBUG
ۻﲮᆖﻆ柚=logging.INFO
ۻﲮᆖﻆ䔎=logging.getLogger
from demo import __version__
__author__="Steve Jackson"
__copyright__="Steve Jackson"
__license__="mit"
ۻﲮᆖﻆ=ۻﲮᆖﻆ䔎(__name__)
def ۻﲮᆖﻆ(n):
 assert n>0
 ۻﲮᆖﻆ関,ۻﲮᆖﻆ=1,1
 for i in ۻﲮᆖﻆ(n-1):
  ۻﲮᆖﻆ関,ۻﲮᆖﻆ=ۻﲮᆖﻆ,ۻﲮᆖﻆ関+ۻﲮᆖﻆ
 return ۻﲮᆖﻆ関
def ۻﲮᆖﻆ(ۻﲮᆖﻆ):
 ۻﲮᆖﻆݻ=ۻﲮᆖﻆﶾ(description="Just a Fibonacci demonstration")
 ۻﲮᆖﻆݻ.add_argument("--version",action="version",version="demo-day {ver}".format(ver=__version__))
 ۻﲮᆖﻆݻ.add_argument(dest="n",help="n-th Fibonacci number",type=ۻﲮᆖﻆ枇,metavar="INT")
 ۻﲮᆖﻆݻ.add_argument("-v","--verbose",dest="loglevel",help="set loglevel to INFO",action="store_const",const=ۻﲮᆖﻆ柚)
 ۻﲮᆖﻆݻ.add_argument("-vv","--very-verbose",dest="loglevel",help="set loglevel to DEBUG",action="store_const",const=ۻﲮᆖﻆ)
 return ۻﲮᆖﻆݻ.ۻﲮᆖﻆ(ۻﲮᆖﻆ)
def ۻﲮᆖﻆ(loglevel):
 ۻﲮᆖﻆ="[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s:%(name)s:%(message)s"
 ۻﲮᆖﻆ닸(level=loglevel,stream=ۻﲮᆖﻆ,format=ۻﲮᆖﻆ,datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
def ۻﲮᆖﻆﯜ(ۻﲮᆖﻆ):
 ۻﲮᆖﻆ=ۻﲮᆖﻆ(ۻﲮᆖﻆ)
 ۻﲮᆖﻆ(ۻﲮᆖﻆ.loglevel)
 ۻﲮᆖﻆ.debug("Starting crazy calculations...")
 ۻﲮᆖﻆ("The {}-th Fibonacci number is {}".format(ۻﲮᆖﻆ.n,ۻﲮᆖﻆ(ۻﲮᆖﻆ.n)))
 ۻﲮᆖﻆ.info("Script ends here")
def ۻﲮᆖﻆܪ():
 ۻﲮᆖﻆﯜ(ۻﲮᆖﻆ[1:])
if __name__=="__main__":
 ۻﲮᆖﻆܪ()
# Created by pyminifier (https://github.com/liftoff/pyminifier)
```